# building a Mybatis query with if

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis

I've written the next code. I know it's wrong, but I don't know how it should really be to do the same. I'll appreciate any help.

```
<select id="getSeqTempByRulesCabN3" resultType="java.lang.Integer" >
    select templat.seq_temp
    from re_t_vp_voucher_template templat, re_t_vp_voucher_rules rules_t, re_t_vp_voucher_rules_pais pais
    where templat.seq_temp = rules_t.seq_temp
                and rules_t.SEQ_RULE = PAIS.SEQ_RULE
    <if test="(select count(*) as cuenta 
        from re_t_vp_voucher_template templat, re_t_vp_voucher_rules rules_t, re_t_vp_voucher_rules_pais pais
        where templat.seq_temp = rules_t.seq_temp
                and rules_t.SEQ_RULE = PAIS.SEQ_RULE
                AND rules_t.seq_rec is not null
                and rules_t.seq_rec = #{seqRec, jdbcType=DECIMAL}
        group by templat.seq_temp,  rules_t.fec_desde_res, rules_t.cod_idioma) != 0">
                and rules_t.seq_rec = #{seqRec, jdbcType=DECIMAL}
    </if>
                and rules_t.seq_ttoo = #{seqTtoo, jdbcType=DECIMAL}
    group by templat.seq_temp,  rules_t.fec_desde_res, rules_t.cod_idioma
</select>
```

Comment: Can you add the error log here as well? Also, from where are you getting the values #{seqRec} and #{seqTtoo} as you have not passed any parameter to the select tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I already know why it doesn't work. You can't simply write an entire sql select query inside the test tag. The test tag only accepts in parameters. Actually, I'm passing the response of the select as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a *horrible* solution for that. If your query works fast enough, maybe this can work.

You condition is `if a!=0 then b`, which can be expressed as `( (a!=0 AND b) OR (a=0) )`

Thus, what I offer is:

```
SELECT templat.seq_temp
FROM re_t_vp_voucher_template templat,
     re_t_vp_voucher_rules rules_t,
     re_t_vp_voucher_rules_pais pais
WHERE templat.seq_temp = rules_t.seq_temp
  AND rules_t.SEQ_RULE = PAIS.SEQ_RULE
  AND rules_t.seq_ttoo = #{seqTtoo, jdbcType=DECIMAL}
  AND ((rules_t.seq_rec = #{seqRec, jdbcType=DECIMAL}
        AND
          (SELECT count(*) AS cuenta
           FROM re_t_vp_voucher_template templat,
                re_t_vp_voucher_rules rules_t,
                re_t_vp_voucher_rules_pais pais
           WHERE templat.seq_temp = rules_t.seq_temp
             AND rules_t.SEQ_RULE = PAIS.SEQ_RULE
             AND rules_t.seq_rec IS NOT NULL
             AND rules_t.seq_rec = #{seqRec, jdbcType=DECIMAL}
           GROUP BY templat.seq_temp,
                    rules_t.fec_desde_res,
                    rules_t.cod_idioma) != 0)
       OR
         (SELECT count(*) AS cuenta
          FROM re_t_vp_voucher_template templat,
               re_t_vp_voucher_rules rules_t,
               re_t_vp_voucher_rules_pais pais
          WHERE templat.seq_temp = rules_t.seq_temp
            AND rules_t.SEQ_RULE = PAIS.SEQ_RULE
            AND rules_t.seq_rec IS NOT NULL
            AND rules_t.seq_rec = #{seqRec, jdbcType=DECIMAL}
          GROUP BY templat.seq_temp,
                   rules_t.fec_desde_res,
                   rules_t.cod_idioma) = 0)
GROUP BY templat.seq_temp,
         rules_t.fec_desde_res,
         rules_t.cod_idioma
```